# python - Selectively choosing nucleotide sequences from a fasta file?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Using biopython how can I snip genes of my interest from a fasta file if the gene names are stored in a text file?

```
#extract genes                
f1 = open('ortholog1.txt','r')
f2 = open('all.fasta','r')
f3 = open('ortholog1.fasta','w')

genes = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f1.readlines()]


i=0
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(f2, "fasta"):
    if genes[i] == seq_record.id:              
        print genes[i]
        f3.write('>'+genes[i])
        i=i+1
        if i==18:
            break
        f3.write('\n')
        f3.write(str(seq_record.seq))
        f3.write('\n')


f2.close()
f3.close()
```

I was trying the above code. But it has some mistakes and is not generic, since like `ortholog1.txt` (which contain gene names) there are 5 more similar files. Also the number of genes in each file varies (not 18 always as here). Here `all.fasta` is the file which contains all genes. `ortholog1.fasta` must contain the snipped nucleotide sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can make Biopython do all the work.

I'm going to guess that the gene names in "ortholog1.txt" are exactly the same as in the fasta file, and that there is one gene name per line.  If not, you'd need to tweak them as necessary to make them line up.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('ortholog1.txt','r') as f:
    orthologs_txt = f.read()
orthologs = orthologs_txt.splitlines()

genes_to_keep = []
for record in SeqIO.parse(open('all.fasta','r'), 'fasta'):
    if record.description in orthologs:
        genes_to_keep.append(record)

with open('ortholog1.fasta','w') as f:
    SeqIO.write(genes_to_keep, f, 'fasta')
```

Edit: Here is one way to keep the output genes in the same order as in the orthologs file:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('all.fasta','r') as fasta_file:
    record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(open(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta')

with open('ortholog1.txt','r') as text_file:
    orthologs_txt = text_file.read()

genes_to_keep = []     
for ortholog in orthologs_txt.splitlines():
    try:
        genes_to_keep.append( record_dict[ortholog] )
    except KeyError:
        pass

with open('ortholog1.fasta','w') as output_file:
    SeqIO.write(genes_to_keep, output_file, 'fasta')
```

Comment: Is there any way to sort the order of genes in the output fasta file according to same order of genes in the ortholog1.txt?

Comment: One way to keep them in order would be to read the records into a dict and then step through the orthologs. See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a biopython expert, so I'll leave the details of the output to you but the data flow can be very simple (the code is commented)

```
# Initially we have a dictionary where the keys are gene names and the
# values are all empty lists
genes = {gene.strip():[] for gene in open('ortholog1.txt','r')}

# parse the data
for record in SeqIO.parse(open('all.fasta','r'), "fasta"):
    # append the current record if its id is in the keys of genes
    if record.id in genes:
       genes[record.id].append(record)

with open('ortholog1.fasta','w') as fout:
    # we read again, line by line, the file of genes
    for gene in open('ortholog1.txt','r'):
        # if the list associated with the current gene is not empty
        if genes[gene.strip()]:
            # output the list of records for the current gene using
            # biopython facilities
            ...
```